# invalid root mapping github project

Tags: android, github

**invalid root mapping androd**

> i have download a project from github and open it in Android Studio it showing following error see image[image: see error image]..

[image: no git folder]

Comment: Did you check that there is actually something in the folder you are looking in?

Comment: @rakwaht can u be more clearer .. becoz i didn't get  can u tell me in detail and 
there are lots of folder in Wall_of_Camera-master folder

Answer (score 0):

Check weather in the folder there is an hidden folder named `.git` that is supposed to contain the git information. If it's not there that is the problem.

Anyway other then that you could probably try to save as backup the current directory and clone it again in a new folder so that you can check if everything is the same.

If you have git in your shell (and I suppose you do since you are on linux) it's really easy, just try something like:

> git clone repo_url

Comment: see i have added image

Comment: You see, the `.git`  folder is not there. I strongly suggest you to clone it from scratch as I suggested up here

Answer (score 0):

Says that the project android studio go configurations are incompatible. Either try to use the project with the git clone option, or delete the hidden .git extension.

Comment: see i have added image

Comment: You can look at what your bottom friend says @beginner

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because Android Studio found a remnant of git (something like `.gitignore`) in the project directory but not found any `.git` folder in the project. So it complaining that the project is supposed having a `.git` and giving an optional to create and set the root directory as a project with git. Other then that, you can work with the project without any problems.

When you downloading the project from the github via `clone or download` -> `download ZIP`, you will losing all the git files of the project. So you losing all the history of the project which is in the git. Instead `download ZIP`, you can clone the project with:

```
git clone remote_project_file
```

Answer (score 0):

When you clone your project from git make sure you do (forgetting the `recursive` flag usually causes the vcs root mapping problem):

```
git clone --recursive YOUR-GIT-URL
```

or if you have already cloned then to fix it:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```